# Did Aldrich Killian believe Extremis to be safe in his case?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-3

In *Iron Man 3* Aldrich Killian displays a rather cavalier attitude to the issue of future refinement of the Extremis treatment, as shown by his [progressively more extravagant use of Extremis effects](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/why-didnt-aldrich-killian-use-the-fire-breathing-in-close-combat-against-tony-s) throughout the film, and also:

> his casual shooting of Maya Hansen when she tries to blackmail him by threatening her own life.

Did he believe that Extremis was sufficiently perfected in his case for his own future safety?

Comment: I took it more that his Extremis use had filled the hole in his brain with a couple of spoonfuls of crazy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took from this that Aldrich was demonstrating that he believed he would have no trouble enforcing his will on Tony to complete the work that was necessary.

As you'll remember, Tony had several years prior just about, while drunk, managed to solve the key problem that Maya was facing in Extremis development.

Maya believed she was totally key to Aldrich's plans, but Aldrich disagreed, as he believed that Tony would be able to fill the gap of a "high level position" created by his shooting Maya.

There's also the clear implication (as mentioned in the comment by Andrew Thompson) to the question that Aldrich isn't exactly operating on normal sanity levels and so perhaps isn't considering the full consequences of his actions.

Comment: After some thought, I've accepted this answer. The key point is that for all her talents, Maya is not a unique genius. Aldrich Killian, by this point has sufficient other options to continue the work that Maya cannot blackmail him successfully.  
Perhaps it need not even be Tony Stark that solves the issues with Extremis. Furthermore, out-of-universe it appears that the plot twist around Maya developed somewhat haphazardly - she was originally meant to be the movie's villain (see http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Maya_Hansen).